# JSONP req.body is not work

Tags: json, node.js, post, jsonp

I'm using nodejs and angular when I clicked on a button on angular side it makes a json post but I use JSONP because of crossdomain problems. When I try to get the data that I sent from client via JSONP I get something like this;

```
{ '{"userName": "something", "password" : "123"}': '' }
```

I get it from req.body on my server.js.

Here is my serverside code

```
    app.post('/', function(req,res){
  console.log("consoleeee:" + req.body);
  res.end();
});
```

and here my client side function that works when clicked the button

```
function loginPageLogin(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) {

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:777/node',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        data: '{"userName": "' + a.value + '", "password" : "' + b.value + '"}'
    })
```

How Can I get req.body correctly? I want it as object. Thank you...

Comment: JSONP works with GET not POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to POST json data using the JSONP transport because JSONP requests are sent by appending a <script> tag to the body of the page, meaning post params cannot be sent, only get params. It also means that the data you are sending needs to be in key/value pairs, not JSON. It can't be synchronous either.

Therefore, You need to decide whether you want to go the JSONP route, or the JSON route with proper CORS setup. If JSONP, organize your paypload as an object, not json, and if json, modify your server to properly handle CORS by adding the CORS middleware.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to change it but Michelem is also right. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change `data` with this so it pushes an object instead a string:

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:777/node',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: {userName: a.value, password: b.value}
    })
```